# Can't compile Golang project that contains submodule

Tags: go, git-submodules, cgo, go-build

I have a Golang project with one git submodule like follows:

Project

- go.mod
- main.go
- config.go
- go-blockchain/ (git Submodule)

  - go.mod
  - crypto/

    - encode.go (This has cgo code in it)
    - crypto.go
  - main.go

When I run `go build` at the top level, I get errors like:

# github.com/blockchain/go-blockchain/crypto

/Users/niceguy/.go/pkg/mod/github.com/blockchain/go-blockchain@v0.0.0-20200320145517-cea8009ba7ee/crypto/encode.go:86:2: could not determine kind of name for C.crypto_encode_pair

/Users/niceguy/.go/pkg/mod/github.com/blockchain/go-blockchain@v0.0.0-20200320145517-cea8009ba7ee/crypto/encode.go:80:2: could not determine kind of name for C.crypto_encode_from_seed

/Users/niceguy/.go/pkg/mod/github.com/blockchain/go-blockchain@v0.0.0-20200320145517-cea8009ba7ee/crypto/encode.go:115:9: could not determine kind of name for C.crypto_encode_proof_to_hash

The problem appears to be that I'm favoring the cache over the CGO libraries that are built and deposited back in the go-blockchain folder.

Suggestions?

Comment: Has this question stumped the internets?

Comment: I found the answer.
I had two separate module addresses in the Golang code referring to the same git submodule.
I had:

github.com/niceguy/myblockchain-proj/go-blockchain
AND
github.com/blockchain/go-blockchain

The answer was to always use the original Golang address of the submodule in the Golang code: github.com/blockchain/go-blockchain and use a _replace_ in go.mod